# How can I open MVC 3 project in Visual studio 2010 SP1 ?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I just reinstalled my OS and installed everything again and found that whenever I open my project I got the error that.

> The project type is not supported by this installation.

Can anyone explain why this happened whenever nothing goes wrong whenever I install.

The issue I found that is error code 1603 and I found later a alternate to install MVC3 you can read the whole post:

[1603 installation Error in MVC 3.](http://geekswithblogs.net/anirugu/archive/2011/04/20/1603-installation-error-in-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: Try creating a new MVC 3 app and inspect the ProjectTypeGuids in the `.proj` file of the app that is failing to open and compare them with those in the new MVC 3 app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to go to the asp.net homepage, download and install the MVC3 package.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Answer (score 6):

There are a few quirks with the web platform installer. Download the full mvc version by clicking on the download for "AspNetMvc3Setup.exe" on this page: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6

Then run the executable, which will get around having to use the web platform installer.

Comment: the provlme is already solved. i hope you read the post i attached in question. i not accept because it's matter that i not accept myself. great link but problem is solved.

Comment: It wasn't working after using the Web Platform Installer but this fixed it for me. Thanks.